# Applying Barycentric coordinates to custom geometry: OGL library

Tags: fragment-shader, vertex-shader, ogl

I have an Icosahedron "position" and "index" array and want to view its edges after applying Barycentric Coordinate effect to it. I have inserted the position and the indexes but something is still missing.

**Problem 1**: It is supposed to show all the triangles of the mesh stroked, but it misses some edges and combines with adjacent triangle.

**Problem 2**: If you un-comment the line  `//aBary = position;` in the vertex shader, it just shows flat colors on the geometry whereas it was supposed to show rgb interpolation like the attached image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, minimal-ui, viewport-fit=cover, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>OGL • Template</title>
    <style>
      :root {
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 100%;
      }
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      import {
        Renderer,
        Camera,
        Transform,
        Geometry,
        Program,
        Mesh,
        Orbit,
        Vec4
      } from "https://unpkg.com/ogl";

      const vertex = `
    attribute vec3 position;
    attribute vec3 points;

    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

    varying vec3 aBary;
    
    void main() {
        aBary = points;
        //aBary = position;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.);
    }
    `;

      const fragment = `
    varying vec3 aBary;
    
    void main() {
        
        float width = 2.;
        vec3 d = fwidth(aBary);
        vec3 s = smoothstep(d * (width + .5), d * (width - .5), aBary);

        gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(s), 1.0);
    }
`;

      const vertex100 =
        /* glsl */ `
      ` + vertex;

      const fragment100 =
        /* glsl */ `#extension GL_OES_standard_derivatives : enable
        precision highp float;
        ` + fragment;

      const vertex300 =
        /* glsl */ `#version 300 es
      #define attribute in
      #define varying out
      ` + vertex;

      const fragment300 =
        /* glsl */ `#version 300 es
      precision highp float;
      #define varying in
      #define texture2D texture
      #define gl_FragColor FragColor
      out vec4 FragColor;
      ` + fragment;

      const renderer = new Renderer({ dpr: 2 });
      const gl = renderer.gl;
      document.body.appendChild(gl.canvas);
      gl.clearColor(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1);

      const camera = new Camera(gl, { fov: 75 });
      camera.position.set(0, 0, 3);
      camera.lookAt([0, 0, 0]);

      const controls = new Orbit(camera);

      function resize() {
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        camera.perspective({ aspect: gl.canvas.width / gl.canvas.height });
      }
      window.addEventListener("resize", resize, false);
      resize();

      const scene = new Transform();
      const program = new Program(gl, {
        vertex: renderer.isWebgl2 ? vertex300 : vertex100,
        fragment: renderer.isWebgl2 ? fragment300 : fragment100,
        cullFace: null
      });

      // Iconsahedron from THREE.js
      const t = (1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2;
      let ico = {
        position: [
        - 1, t, 0,  1, t, 0,    - 1, - t, 0,    1, - t, 0,
        0, - 1, t,  0, 1, t,    0, - 1, - t,    0, 1, - t,
        t, 0, - 1,  t, 0, 1,    - t, 0, - 1,    - t, 0, 1
        ],
        index: [
        0, 11, 5,   0, 5, 1,    0, 1, 7,    0, 7, 10,   0, 10, 11,
        1, 5, 9,    5, 11, 4,   11, 10, 2,  10, 7, 6,   7, 1, 8,
        3, 9, 4,    3, 4, 2,    3, 2, 6,    3, 6, 8,    3, 8, 9,
        4, 9, 5,    2, 4, 11,   6, 2, 10,   8, 6, 7,    9, 8, 1
        ]
      };
      
      let data = new Float32Array(36);

      for (let i = 0; i < 36; i+=12) {
          data.set([ 0,0,1, 0,1,0, 1,0,0 ], i )
      }


      let geometry = new Geometry(gl,
          {
              position: {size: 3, data: new Float32Array(ico.position)},
              index: { data: new Uint16Array(ico.index)},
              points: {size: 3, data: data}
          } 
      );


      let mesh = new Mesh(gl, { geometry, program });
      mesh.position.set(0, 0, 0);
      mesh.setParent(scene);

      requestAnimationFrame(update);

      function update(t) {
        renderer.render({ scene, camera });
        controls.update();
        requestAnimationFrame(update);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]